# Samsung dishwasher dispenser doesn't open until partway through rinse cycle

Tags: dishwasher, soap-dispenser

We have a Samsung DMR57LFB dishwasher that is about 6 years old. The past two weeks or so we noticed a new problem -- soap on the glasses after the dishwasher was finished. So I watched during the 2 hour 14 minute complete cycle. During the 1 hour 30 minute wash the soap dispenser stayed closed. It then opened about 5 minutes into the rinse, with 40 minutes remaining in the complete cycle. That left unrinsed soap on the dishes.

My understanding is that when a dishwasher starts a complete cycle it first rinses the dishes, drains,and then starts to wash, at which point the soap dispenser opens. I guess we could manually open the dispenser at that point but I'd like to fix this if I could. The soap dispenser seems to operate fine, but just get the control signal late.

Any suggestions on what to try to find and fix the problem? I'll try pulling the plug on the dishwasher to see if that resets the control board.

Comment: I am not sure this platform will solve this for you, but it might.  I have had much better luck on appliance repair forums that are run by part sellers.  Those are fantastic resources.

Comment: Evil Elf, thanks, I'll try a forum like that too.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know if this is a new problem or a new unit. The first thing that comes to mind is "Are you sure you are putting the dish washing soap in the right dispenser"?

I looked up the manual to your particular model here:

[Samsung Manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/145912/Samsung-Dmr57lhb.html?page=18#manual)

You can see on page 18 and 19 it differentiates between the two dispensers. The behavior your are describing is what I would expect from the rinse aid dispenser.

I also once had issue with dishes blocking the latch from opening completely. For instance, placing a sheet pan parallel to the door. The door would open slightly and the dishwasher tab would not dissolve properly until the rinse cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is an old dishwasher with a new problem. I made sure the soap dispenser was not blocked and opened the door every 5 to 10 minutes during the complete cycle to see when the dispenser opened. It opened fine, but about 5 minutes into the rinse cycle instead of in the wash cycle.